# Spawning bash time from Node.js Child Process

Tags: node.js, time, benchmarking

I am using `child_process.exec()` to execute the command `time <my application>`.

If I run this command in the terminal, my application is timed with Linux's `time(1)` command. However when executing the same command from a Node.js script `child_process.exec(time <my application>);`, my application is timed with GNU Time instead.

This is problematic because I need the millisecond precision of `time(1)` which GNU Time does not provide.

How can I call `time(1)` from `child_process.exec()`? I have tried giving the full path to `time(1)` instead of just `time`, however this did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I was successfully able to enforce use of `time(1)` by wrapping my command in the following format: child_process.exec(`/bin/bash -c "time <my application>")`.